# Filter against an array condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

Let's say I have an array of userIds

```
const userIds = ['1234', '3212', '1122']
```

And then I have an array of objects

```
const arrayOfObjects = [
  {
    _source: {itemId: ['1234'] }
  },
  {
    _source: {itemId: ['3212'] }
  },
  {
    _source: {itemId: ['1111'] }
  }
]
```

I want to filter my array of objects by matching ids to the userIds array

`arrayOfObjects.filter(item => item._source.itemId === "what goes here?")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
arrayOfObjects.filter(item => userIds.includes(item._source.itemId[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) isn't supported by Internet Explorer. If you want a cross browser solution you could use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) methods:

```js
const userIds = ['1234', '3212', '1122'];
const arrayOfObjects = [{
    _source: {
      itemId: ['1234']
    }
  },
  {
    _source: {
      itemId: ['3212']
    }
  },
  {
    _source: {
      itemId: ['1111']
    }
  }
];

const filtered = arrayOfObjects.filter(o => userIds.indexOf(o['_source'].itemId[0]) > -1);

console.log(filtered)
```